# Array containing reference to winform controls

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I'm working on a winform project using Visual Studio 2010. I noticed this happening when creating array that contains reference to Button (or any other winform controls). If I write it like this:

```
Button[] buttonArray;
buttonArray = {Button1, Button2};
```

I will get multiple errors like `Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as a statement` and `Invalid expression term '{'` to name a few.

For your info, Button1 and Button2 are on the form.

Even when I do it this way, I still get the same errors:

```
Button[] buttonArray = new Button[2];
buttonArray = { Button1, Button2};
```

However, if I do it like this, it's accepted by Visual Studio:

```
Button[] buttonArray = new Button[2];
buttonArray[0] = Button1;
buttonArray[1] = Button2;
```

So can anyone tell me what went wrong? I thought array containing reference to controls have the same essence as array of strings.

Thank you.

Comment: your syntax is wrong, that's all

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you do this:

```
Button[] buttonArray;
buttonArray = {Button1, Button2};
```

you're not using the `array initialization` syntax. What you're doing is declaring a button array but not instantiating it, and then attempting to assign that `buttonArray` to a block of code. The array initialization syntax is not valid outside of assignment. Something like

```
void MyMethod()
{
    string[] s;
    { 
        int i = 0; 
    }
}
```

is a valid code block in C#; the curlies inside the method just alter scope. You're not able to assign the code block to a variable, such as this case:

```
void MyMethod()
{
    string[] s;
    s = 
    {
        int i = 0; 
    }; //Totally INVALID!
}
```

You need to combine the declaration and initialization, or `new` up the array.

```
Button[] buttonArray = { Button1, Button2 }; //Valid

Button[] buttonArray;
buttonArray = new Button[] { Button1, Button2 }; //Also valid!
```

Comment: Accepted this answer because it clearly explains what actually happens in this ( `buttonArray = {Button1, Button2};` ) line of code. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 4):

Try to use [array initialization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0a7fscd0.aspx) syntax

```
Button[] buttonArray = new [] { Button1, Button2 };
```

or

```
Button[] buttonArray;
buttonArray = new [] { Button1, Button2};
```

you can also  substitute `Button[]` with `var` in the first example, since C# compiler is smart enough to infer types from initialization part.

Arrays can also be initialized without using `new []` near variable declaration. In your case it would be

```
Button[] buttonArray = { Button1, Button2 };
```

But note, that you can't use `var` keyword, when you use such syntax. So next code is **illegal**:

```
var buttonArray = { Button1, Button2 }; //won't compile
```

Comment: even the `new[]` is not needed.

Answer (score 2):

Correct array initialization syntax is defined here : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa287601(v=VS.71).aspx